# Colour functions within IE Filter for Gradients

Tags: less

Have tried various "escape" functions but can't seem to get the below working...

```
.background-radial(@colour, @depth: 20%) {
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{colour}', endColorstr='darken(@{colour},@{depth})',GradientType=1 )"; /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

called by

```
body {
    .background-radial(rgb(225,225,255));
}
```

Renders as

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e1e1e1', endColorstr='darken(#e1e1e1,20)',GradientType=1 );
```

Problem is trying to ensure the "darken" (or any other colour function) works within the filter escape. I'm guessing i've been using the escape sequences incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work around this through an extra variable:

```
.background-radial(@colour, @depth: 20%) {
    @newColour: darken(@colour, @depth);
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{colour}', endColorstr='@{newColour})',GradientType=1 )"; /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Comment: Why didn't i think of that! Thanks